# Using data in google sheets as input to add csv layer to QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, online, google-sheets

I have a google sheets spreadsheet that contains XCoord and YCoord columns and some other columns. I want to use this sheet as (preferably live) input to create a point layer in QGIS. My approach is to publish my google sheet as a csv file, and use the published url as the file location in the Add delimited Text Layer dialog in QGIS. I cannot get this approach to work.

How do I do this?